# Upon deployment JBoss EAP 6.4.0 cannot find (remote) host names provided in standalone.xml

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, war, ear

I am trying to deploy an application provided to me. It should deploy an EAR application on a JBoss EAP server. I ran a configuration script (also given) which applies the following to the standalone.xml file:

For sake of anonymity I have changed the host/-app names to NAME_ONE, NAME_TWO, and APP_NAME.

Mail target:

```
<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
    <remote-destination host="NAME_ONE" port="25"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

Database:

```
<connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://NAME_TWO/APP_NAME</connection-url>
```

When I try to run the server it gives me following exceptions:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.mail-session.java:jboss/mail/Default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.mail-session.java:jboss/mail/Default: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1936) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS015451: Unknown host for outbound socket binding configuration 'mail-smtp'.
    at org.jboss.as.mail.extension.MailSessionService.getServerSocketAddress(MailSessionService.java:169)
    at org.jboss.as.mail.extension.MailSessionService.setServerProps(MailSessionService.java:133)
    at org.jboss.as.mail.extension.MailSessionService.getProperties(MailSessionService.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.mail.extension.MailSessionService.start(MailSessionService.java:65)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: NAME_ONE
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at org.jboss.as.network.OutboundSocketBinding.getDestinationAddress(OutboundSocketBinding.java:146)
    at org.jboss.as.mail.extension.MailSessionService.getServerSocketAddress(MailSessionService.java:167)
    ... 8 more
```

When I try to deploy the application a similar exception occurs for both the mail target and the database:

```
18:30:17,071 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:356)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:304)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:834)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:379)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:453)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:425)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:354)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:368)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:510)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:242) [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:117) [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:85) [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184) [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156) [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1827) [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1785) [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:150)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:123)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:28)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:20)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:391)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:265)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:328)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: NAME_TWO
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:60)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:74)
    ... 37 more
```

In a desperate attempt I tried to add both names to the hosts file but that did not work. If it helps in any way: the server does say that the PostgreSQL driver has been deployed successfully on it in its management console.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the database I was trying to connect to did not exist. I received the database and then used pgAdmin to restore it. I then changed the location to my localhost:port and it was able to connect to the database.